# list within a list within a list in python

Tags: python

I wrote this but I don't understand why it is not working. By the way I am a beginner in programming.

```
fav_colours=[["bob"["likes:blue, hates:red"]],["john"["likes:red,hates:black"]],  
["adam"["likes:purple,hates:pink"]]]
print fav_colours
```

I don't think there is any error.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to separate each list item via a comma, so `["bob"["likes:blue, hates:red"]` should be `["bob", ["likes:blue, hates:red"]`.

And it looks like you might need to use a `dict` instead of those inner lists. `{"likes": "blue"}`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Russell Dias answer:

Having **multiple nested lists** gets you in issues, e.g. if you want to

- **access data from a specific person**. E.g. if you want the data for John, you have to know that John has the index 1 in the list.
- **check for existence of a person** -> you will have to iterate over the whole list and compare it. The same counts if you want to avoid duplicates.

To handle these points you can substitute the outer list with a dictionary. Further I assume that the like and hate parts should have been seperate strings:

```
>>> fav_colours_dict = { "bob" : ["likes:blue", "hates:red"],
... "john" : ["likes:red", "hates:black"],
... "adam" : ["likes:purple", "hates:pink"] }

>>> print fav_colours_dict["john"]
['likes:red', 'hates:black']
```

Next thing to notice is that you are possibly just interested in the color string, like "blue" without the "likes:" or "hates:" prefix. In fact alone by the list position you already have that information, since 0 indexes the "likes" and 1 the "hates". Further, as no further position makes sense, it is best to change the color lists to tuples, with `()`.

So the dictionary changes to:

```
>>> fav_colours_dict = { "bob" : ("blue", "red"),
... "john" : ("red", "black"),
... "adam" : ("purple", "pink")}
```

Now with setting

```
>>> likes, hates = range(2)    # likes = 0, hates = 1
```

you can access the "likes" color from adam with:

```
>>> print fav_colours_dict["adam"][likes]
purple
```

In the case you want to add several colors for likes or hates the best way is using a set, with `{}`. This ensures that no color is used twice:

```
>>> fav_colours_dict = { "bob" : ({"blue", "yellow"}, {"red"}),
>>> ... "john" : ({"red"}, {"black", "green"}),
>>> ... "adam" : ({"purple", "black"}, {"pink"}) }

>>> print fav_colours_dict
{'bob': (set(['blue', 'yellow']), set(['red'])), 'john': (set(['red']),
set(['black', 'green'])), 'adam': (set(['purple', 'black']), set(['pink']))}
```

Seeing the output above you will probably want better print:

```
>>> for person, colours in fav_colours_dict.iteritems():
...     print person
...     print "- likes: " + ", ".join(colours[likes])
...     print "- hates: " + ", ".join(colours[hates])
...
bob
- likes: blue, yellow
- hates: red
john
- likes: red
- hates: black, green
adam
- likes: purple, black
- hates: pink
```

So in the end you used the most common data structures of python: dictionaries, tuples and sets.